# Custom Adapter with complex data fetching

Tags: android, database, android-recyclerview

I'm making an app that fetches movies from 6 different cinemas webs. I'm parsing the HTML with Jsoup in order to find the movies that are being played in each cinema.

After getting each title. I'm consuming a movies API to get the movie's data. Once I get the data, I add the movie to de adapter.

The thing is that I'm adding each movie to the adapter independently and I need to check if the movie is already there so I can update the element to add which cinema is showing the movie.

**What would be the best way of doing this?** Right now I'm checking if the movie id that I get from the API is already in the adapter. I update the element and add a the cinema that is also showing the movie.

Besides that. I'm facing another problem. Some movies have different titles in different cinemas (translation issues) and the API i'm consuming only allows 40 request every 10 seconds. I'm trying to prevent the app of fetching the movie data if I already have the movie inside de adapter. But I cannot compare the titles to check if is already there because they might be different.

**Might a good solution be to fetch all movies and saved them in a DB and only after the fetching part ended populate the adapter with all the movies?**

**Should I use some kind of map instead of an ArrayList to improve performance** when I'm checking if the movie title is already in the adapter and/or the movie id is already in the adapter?

**Am I missing a way to reduce API calls?**

Thank you for your help. I'm not asking for code, just your thoughts on this, and what would be the best way of doing it. For performance and reduce of network usage.

Comment: have you read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html)?

Comment: I'll take a look now.